# How to toggle delete/update user meta values?

Tags: user-meta

I have multiple forms which stores extra user fields in usermeta table. For this i use

`foreach($user_meta_fields as $user_meta_field){
If($_POST[$user_meta_field] !=''){
      update_user_meta($current_user->ID, $user_meta_field, $_POST[$user_meta_field]);
}
    }`

But now i like to delete a meta key if an user decides to uncheck that particular input field. How can i do this?

Should i read all stored meta keys and compare with the meta keys in $_POST?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just use [delete_user_meta()?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta) in an `else` statement?

Comment: @AndrewBartel, i realise i need to use delete_user_meta but i am having trouble with the logic. In my case for example an user has selected input fields a b x y and z. And the next day he selects input fields c x y z, hence he deselects a and b. So how do i setup the logic to delete_user_meta and update_user_meta? regards

Comment: tryint to simplify my issue. Is this logic correct?
`$meta_fields_from_post = array('c','x','y','z');
$meta_fields_stored = array('a','b','x','y','z');
$fields_filtered_to_delete = array_diff( $meta_fields_from_post, $meta_fields_stored);`